# Seleccionar una parte del texto en un TextField

Tags: javafx

Quiero seleccionar una parte de un texto de un control `javaFX` `TextField` de igual forma que hacía con `Java` en un JTextField de esta forma:

```
controlTexto.setSelectionStart(inicio);
controlTexto.setSelectionEnd(final);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de seleccionar un texto dentro de un control `TextField` en `JavaFX` es mediante el método selectRange:

```
miTextField.selectRange(posiciónInicial, cantidadCaracteres);
```